# DocuSignAPI: Optional Custom Text Tab with value can't be modified

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to create a tab via the DocuSign API with the following requirements:

- Optional
- Text
- Anchored
- Shared
- Has a Default Value

However, when i set the value of the tab before composing and sending the envelope, the tab will not be editable to any of the Recipients. See code below:

```
private static Tab buildOptionalInputTab(String recId, String docId, String defaultValue)
{
    Tab tab = new Tab();
    tab.RecipientID = recId;
    tab.AnchorTabItem = new AnchorTab { AnchorTabString = "Tracking #:" };
    tab.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 135;
    tab.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = -8;
    tab.DocumentID = docId;
    tab.Type = TabTypeCode.Custom;
    tab.CustomTabRequiredSpecified = true;
    tab.CustomTabRequired = false;
    tab.CustomTabType = CustomTabType.Text;
    tab.Name = "Tracking #";
    tab.SharedTabSpecified = true;
    tab.SharedTab = true;
    tab.Value = defaultValue; //REMOVE THIS LINE AND IT WORKS            

    return tab;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `tab.Locked = false;` to your SOAP request and you should be able to set the default value while also making it editable.